# How do I save table from prettytable?

Tags: python, numpy, prettytable

So I am using the library 'prettytable' and am able to get a table of my data printed upon execution. However, I have no idea how to save it to a file. Ideally I'd like the table to be saved in a pdf so I could use it for my report.

Here is an example code from the prettytable webpage itself:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])
x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names
x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
print x
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `get_string()` method, docstring quote:

```
def get_string(self, **kwargs):

    """Return string representation of table in current state.
       ...
    """
```

Example:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])

...

data = x.get_string()

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

This will create a `test.txt` file with your prettytable inside.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just tried that:

data = x.get_string()
numpy.savetxt(('data.txt'),data)

and got an Indexerror: Tuple index out of range.

Comment: @user2869276 I've included an example that writes the data to a text file, please check.

Comment: This works! I tried to save my prettytable.get_string() in a .csv file. The only thing to add is------ 
with open('file.csv', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f: 

Hope someone finds this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

@Komal Jaswani
You should change 'wb' mode to 'w' mode.

`with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(data)`

Answer (score 1):

using open and write method to save data to test.txt file.

Try the following code,

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

The above snippet will throw an error as the `data` will be of type prettytable. You need to typecast the `data` object to a `str` first, like this:

```
data = str(data) 
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: 
    f.write(data)
```

The file will now be saved locally.